# Using incremental number when registering new user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im trying to do something very simple: every time someone new user signup i want to give him a special id ("ab_id") that will be automatically incremented (first = 1, second = 2, etc...)

How do i acheive this with my "beforeSave" function for the "Users" table?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {

    // I need some kind of running number here

    var running_number = ???

    request.object.set("ab_id",12);
    response.success();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `Counter` object - and keep its access restricted to the master key only. Then use it like this (the code assumes that a `Counter` object with `type` of `"users"` already exists):

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query("Counter");
query.equalTo("type", "users");
query.first().then(function(counter) {
    counter.increment("count");
    return counter.save();
}).then(function(counter) {
    // your code here
    var running_number = counter.get("count");

    // etc..

}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

The `increment` method is atomic, so you got that covered.